# Angular.js: Highchart click event not updating the data in table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I have a bar chart, where When I click on a bar in the chart, it should display the corresponding result in a table data list(in my case appList). Currently this is not happening. When I click on a bar, lets say ("Pending" - should display 4) it still displays me all(14) results.

Highchart plot options:

```
plotOptions: {
            column: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    crop: false,
                    formatter: function () {
                        return this.y.toFixed(0);
                    },
                    overflow: 'none'
                },
                cursor: 'pointer',
                pointPadding: 0.1,
                borderWidth: 0,
                colorByPoint: true,
                events: {
                    click: function (event) {

                        switch (event.point.category) {
                            case 'Inprogress':
                                $scope.displayAppInfo('Inprogress');
                                alert($scope.appList.length)
                                break;
                            case 'Completed':
                                $scope.displayAppInfo('Completed');
                                break;
                            case 'Pending':
                                $scope.displayAppInfo('Pending');
                                break;
                            case 'Unable to Complete':
                                $scope.displayAppInfo('Unable to Complete');
                                break;  
                                
                            case 'All':
                                $scope.displayAppInfo('All');
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Display app info function

```
 $scope.displayAppInfo = function (input) {
    // $scope.appList = [];
    $scope.appStatusName = '';
    // $scope.search = {};
    if(input == 'Unable to Complete'){
        $scope.appList = 5 results(array of objects);
    }else if(input == 'Pending'){
        $scope.appList = 4 results(array of objects);
    }else if(input == 'Completed'){
        $scope.appList = 2 results(array of objects);
    }else if(input == 'In progress'){
        $scope.appList = 3 results(array of objects);
    }else if(input == 'All'){
        $scope.appList = 14 results(array of objects);
        $scope.appStatusName = 'All';
    }
}

HTML:
<div>
 <table>
  <table body><table row ng-repeat="a in app List">{{a}}</table 
 row> 
 </table body></table>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you reproduce your issue with the sample data on some online editor?

Comment: What's version of your Angular?